# Run jar that depends on external jars inside JRE folder

Tags: java, linux

Case: all external jar files are in the folder
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0.151-1jpp.5.el7.x86_64/lib/ext

I need to run my executable JAR that uses these jar files internally. Do I need to specify them when explicitly starting my jar, or since they are inside the JRE directory, will they be automatically pulled up?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  They’re loaded automatically.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html.  Be warned, later Java versions have deprecated the extensions directory.

Answer (score 0):

The jar files inside the jre folder will be found automatically because you must have set the path of java to the folder in the system path.

Comment: Java does not use the JAVA_HOME variable.  At all.  There are many third party tools which use it, but Java itself does not.

Comment: Updated the answer.